# RegEx : Replace parts of dynamic strings

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

I have a string

**IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),**

I need to remove IsNull part, so the result would be

**VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,**

I'm absolute new to RegEx, but it wouldn't be a problem, if not one thing :
VSK1 is dynamic part, can be any combination of A-Z,0-9 and any length.  How to replace strings with RegEx?   I use MSSQL 2k5, i think it uses general set of RegEx rules.

EDIT : I forgot to say, that I'm doing replacement in SSMS Query window's Replace Box (^H) - not building RegEx query

br
marius

Comment: "I use MSSQL 2k5, i think it uses general set of RegEx rules." This is not true unless you enable CLR and compile and install an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

here's a regex that should work:

```
[^(]+\(([^,]+),[^)]\)
```

Then use `$1` capture group to extract the part that you need.

I did a sanity check in ruby:

```
orig = "IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),"
regex = /[^(]*\(([^,]+),[^)]\)/
result = orig.sub(regex){$1} # result => VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,
```

It gets trickier if you have a prefix that you want to retain. Like if you have this:

```
"somestuff = IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),"
```

In this case, you need someway to identify the start of the pattern. Maybe you can use '=' to identify the start of the pattern? If so, this should work:

```
orig = "somestuff = IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),"
regex = /=\s*\w+\(([^,]+),[^)]\)/
result = orig.sub(regex){$1} # result => somestuff = VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,
```

But then the case where you don't have an equals sign will fail. Maybe you can use 'IsNull' to identify the start of the pattern? If so, try this (note the '/i' representing case insensitive matching):

```
orig = "somestuff = isnull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),"
regex = /IsNull\(([^,]+),[^)]\)/i 
result = orig.sub(regex){$1} # result => somestuff = VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I have long script, and these strings are only a part of this.. Your script find part I need, but also a lot of characters before, if my string is not in the beging of line : VSK1_DVal_SUM          = isnull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0) This is my line and your regex will select all string, not part from IsNull(...

Comment: Hi bala, I added two more examples that will hopefully help you retain prefixes. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Dave, since I have to replace IsNul.., it could be used as start of the pattern. I'll try your solution and inform if all went well

Comment: oh, boy. none of these find anything. well, looks like'll have to go easier way - to write some sort of text parser with c#. it is to much effort to learn RegEx just for one project...

Answer (score 0):

```
/IsNULL\((A-Z0-9+),0\)/
```

Then pick group match number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very useful site:  http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

They have a tester and a cheatsheet that are very useful for quick testing of this sort.

I tested the solution by Dave and it works fine except it also removes the trailing comma you wanted retained.  Minor thing to fix.

Try this:

```
IsNULL\((.*,)0\)
```

Comment: this one finds string with no problems. but how to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question

> I use MSSQL 2k5, i think it uses
>   general set of RegEx rules.

This is not true unless you enable CLR and compile and install an assembly. You can use its native pattern matching syntax and `LIKE` for this as below.

```
WITH T(C) AS
(

SELECT 'IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,0),' UNION ALL
SELECT 'IsNull(VSK1_DVal.RuntimeSUM,123465),'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'No Match'
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(C,8,1+LEN(C)-8-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(C),2))
FROM T
WHERE C LIKE 'IsNull(%,_%),'
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I absolutely forget to say, that I need to replace in SSMS Query window, not directly in TSQL...